# Is SQLite3 supported on GAE for PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, sqlite

Is SQLite3 supported in Google App Engine for PHP ?
php-minishell's [phpinfo](http://php-minishell.appspot.com/phpinfo) doesn't show so.
But a phpinfo() script on my development machine at localhost:8080/phpinfo shows sqlite3.
I understand GAE is a read-only access and hence SQLite3 cannot be supported, but how are extension list different ?

Comment: On your local development server you also have your local PHP installation. The suggestion normally is that you install the same PHP version as well as that you try to mimic the extension list. But different to google app engine, on your local development server you are able to configure differently. It does not make much sense to do that, however it is possible. With your development server you're the boss, in google app engine, google is the boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are part of php, not gae. On your local machine you have `sqlite` module enabled in  ini file, on appspot you don't have that luxury:

> Some modules have been disabled because their core functions are not supported by App Engine, such as networking or **writing to the filesystem**.

(from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime?hl=en#Pure_PHP)

Answer (score 0):

No, but there is a feature request to add SQLite3 to GAE, so please [star it](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9423).

Comment: Google should really consider adding PHP SQLite support... starred it!

Comment: They've recently closed this request saying that GCS doesn't provide concurrent read&write operations.